# Python3 Extracting lines between first instance of two markers

Tags: python-3.x

I imported a text file from URL and want to process it. The file looks as below. There are two instances of " innings " and "Extras   ". I want to extract lines between the FIRST instance of " innings " and FIRST instance of "Extras   ". The code that I wrote extracts ALL instances. How do I resolve this?

> Toss: Sri Lanka   Umpires: M Erasmus (South Africa) and NJ Llong
>   (England)   TV umpire: S Ravi (India)   Match referee: DC Boon
>   (Australia)   Reserve umpire: SD Fry (Australia)   Player of the
>   match: CJ Anderson   New Zealand **innings** (50 overs maximum)
>   R   M   B  4 6   MJ Guptill            c Sangakkara       b Lakmal
>   49  94  62  5 0   CJ Anderson           c Lakmal           b
>   Kulasekara          75  77  46  8 2
>   +L Ronchi             not out                                  29  29  19  4 0
>   **Extras**                (lb 2, w 8, nb 3)                        13   Total                 (6 wickets, 50 overs, 226 mins)         331
>   Sri Lanka **innings** (target: 332 runs from 50 overs)              R 
>   M   B  4 6   HDRL Thirimanne                          b Boult
>   65  90  60  8 0   RAS Lakmal            not out
>   7  21  17  0 0
>   **Extras**                (w 10, nb 1)                             11   Total                 (all out, 46.1 overs, 210 mins)         233

Here is my code:

```
flag = 1   
for line in data:  
    if " innings " in line:  
         flag = 0  
        print('')  
    if line.startswith("Extras   "):  
        flag = 1  
        print('')  
    if not flag and not " innings " in line:  
        print(line)
```

Comment: You have to `break` out of the loop when you encounter "Extras"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program must stop on the first occurrence of `Extras`:

```
active = False # A variable `flag` is not very precisely named,
               # better call it `active`, make it boolean
               # and flip the values
for line in data:  
    if " innings " in line:  
        active = True    # now we want to do things
        print('')
        continue         # but not in this loop
    if line.startswith("Extras   "):  
        print('')  
        break             # now we're done!
        # alternative Method:
        # active = False
    if active:  
        print(line)
```

If you want to store all occurrences:

```
active = False 
stored = []
for line in data:  
    if " innings " in line:
        tmp = []
        active = True    # now we want to do things
        continue         # but not in this loop
    if line.startswith("Extras   "):
        stored.append(tmp)
        active = False
        continue
    if active:  
        tmp.append(line)
```

You'll end up with a list of lists of lines for further processing.

Comment: Works like a charm! Can I save this output to Pandas dataframe? You know what, let me try first before I seek help.

Comment: What if I want the output of a second instance too? But it should be stored separately. By bailing out of loop after encountering first "Extras   ", we get the first instance. Second seems trickier.